# retain text box value on window.location

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form as follows:

```
<form name="donation_form" action="" method="post" target="_self">
<select  name="donationType" onChange="window.location='?page=donate&amp;donationType='+donation_form.donationType.value;">
<option>--Select--</option>
<option value="a" selected="selected">a</option>
<option value="b" >b</option>
<option value="c" >c</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="amount"  />
<select  name="giftAid" onChange="window.location='?page='+donate+'&amp;donationType='+a+'&amp;amount='+donation_form.amount.value+'&amp;giftAid='+donation_form.giftAid.value;">
<option>--Select--</option>
<option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
<option value="No" >No</option>
</select>
<input name="submit2" type="submit" value="Make a Donation" />
</form>
```

Now when I select the second select and it refreshes the page, how do I retain the value of the amount text box that a user has enetered as well as the two selects?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Abdul, SO works on question answer basis, meaning that if you ask questions, you're generally expected to pick an answer if one has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should accept answers for your older questions.

---

You'll need to pass the values of the other controls to the server as querystring parameters, then set the selected values of the options in server-side code (or Javascript) from the querystring.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to refresh the page with the selected value without loosing what the user entered in the text box

Comment: Why are you trying to refresh the page?